# Disable Media.RequestProtection when page is in preview mode

Tags: experience-editor, media-library, mediaurls

I have `Media.RequestProtection` enabled in my Sitecore 10.0 instance.

Is there way to disable this only for preview and experience editor mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can update the setting on the page request but if you see where the setting is being used in the code, I think you can control the setting. For example, I found that this is being used in the class called  `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequest` that you can find under the DLL called `Sitecore.Kernel`.

I found that by extracting the whole DLL. I think using statements like `Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing` or `Context.PageMode.IsPreview`, you can allow this setting to be true or false.

And after extending the class you can apply a patch like this to use your class.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <requestParser patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequest, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="namespace.CustomMediaRequest,  assembly" />
    </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Updating my answer as per your comments:

You will find a property in the `Settings.cs` with `public static class RequestProtection` to enable of disable the Media Request Protection like below. And you can add a check here as need.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a value indicating whether Media Request Protection feature enabled.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///   <c>true</c> if Media Request Protection feature enabled; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </value>
public static bool Enabled
{
  get
  {
    if (!Settings.Media.RequestProtection._enabled.HasValue)
      Settings.Media.RequestProtection._enabled = new bool?(Settings.SettingsInstance.Media().RequestProtection().Enabled);
    return Settings.Media.RequestProtection._enabled.Value;
  }
  internal set => Settings.Media.RequestProtection._enabled = new bool?(value);
}
```

I hope this way you can control this.

Comment: with this approach we will be handling the behavior via code. But as this is default Sitecore OOTB functionality so this Media Request Protection should not throw error by default in preview mode also.

Comment: @rahul You just need to change the functionality for the code that you need and don't need to modify the rest of the code. So it will not impact the OOTB one. This way you can add the check for experience editor or preview mode.

Comment: Can you provide more details on code snippet. as i am seeing the values for media protection can't be modified via code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try customizing `MediaProvider` and `GetMediaUrl` to get the URL without `hash` while accessing media in preview mode.

1. Create a custom `MediaProvider`

```
public class MediaProvider : Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider
    {
        public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlBuilderOptions options)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");

            bool isPreviewMode = Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview;

            var url = base.GetMediaUrl(item, options);

            if (isPreviewMode)
            {
                return url;
            }

            return HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(url);
        }
    }
```

2. Update the config change using the patch.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <mediaLibrary>
      <mediaProvider patch:instead="mediaProvider[@type='Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel']"
                     type="YourProjectNameSpace.MediaProvider, YourProjectNameSpace" />
  </mediaLibrary>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Another way is to disable for the specific core role by setting `Media.RequestProtection.Enabled` to `false`.

Patch the file to update the setting value.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
     <setting name="Media.RequestProtection.Enabled" value="false" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How we achieve this disable for the specific core role ?

Comment: You can disable for CM role. Go to App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config and  change as <setting name="Media.RequestProtection.Enabled" value="false" />

Comment: will disabling this will have any impact in normal and experience editor mode. And is there way to disable this via patch file.

Comment: If you disable it will not impact any functionality for normal or experience editor mode. Yes you can do it via patch file.

Comment: Updated answer with patch file for updating setting value.